Using reflection to set an entry value in generic dictionary
I am attempting to use System.Reflection to modify values in a generic dictionary in which I do not know the types of the IKey and IValue.  I am able to set the values of the Dictionary.Entry.value for each entry in the dictionary using a series of GetField(), GetValue(), and SetValue() statements (code below), but the values returned by dict[key] still return the unaltered values.
Here is simple example of what I want to do (real code is after this):
dict["some key"] = "some value";
// Use reflection to do a SetValue dict.entries[0] to "some new value"
Printing out dict["some key"] should now display "some new value"

Instead, it prints out the original value.  In the code below you'll see that the key is a match, and a GetValue() call after the SetValue() retrieves the new value.  I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.
Here is the code:
const BindingFlags BINDING_FLAGS_ALL = (BindingFlags) 65535;
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["key1"] = "original value";
object entry = ((Array) dict.GetType().GetField("entries", BINDING_FLAGS_ALL).GetValue(dict)).GetValue(0);
object key = entry.GetType().GetField("key", BINDING_FLAGS_ALL).GetValue(entry);
FieldInfo val_field = entry.GetType().GetField("value", BINDING_FLAGS_ALL);
object val = val_field.GetValue(entry);
Console.WriteLine($"original value at '{key}' == '{val}'");
val_field.SetValue(entry, "changed value!");
val = val_field.GetValue(entry);
Console.WriteLine($"new value at '{key}' == '{val}'");
val = dict[(string) key];
Console.WriteLine($"dict[{key}] == '{val}'");

The output is:
original value at 'key1' == 'original value'
new value at 'key1' == 'changed value!'
dict[key1] == 'original value'

Thanks in advance for the guidance!
dd

I'm kind of confused by the end goal here... how would you change the value of an entry if you don't even know what type the value is? How would you know which key(s) to modify if you don't know the type of the keys?

Dictionary<TKey,TValue> implements the non-generic IDictionary - can you not just use that?

Don't do this. As it relies on private implementation, it's very fragile and platform-dependent. It does not even work on .NET [Core] where the field names have an underscore prefix. And why is that BindingFlags value with setting the lower-half bits without thinking, instead of a meaningful constant? Why don't you just cast dict to IDictionary and use the non-generic indexer?

Update
As pointed out in the comments, you can cast the dictionary to a non-generic IDictionary first:
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
((IDictionary)dict)["key1"] = "changed value!";
// Works
((IDictionary)dict)[10] = 50;
// Also works, just generates
// an exception because the dictionary is of type string
// (but at least compiles and runs)


Original answer
Each type that has an indexer also includes hidden methods: get_Item and set_Item.
My approach is to invoke the set_Item method with reflection:
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["key1"] = "original value";
var type = dict.GetType();
var setItemMethod = type.GetMethod("set_Item");
setItemMethod.Invoke(dict, new object[] { "key1", "changed value!" });
Console.WriteLine(dict["key1"]);

This program will display the output changed value!.
It works even for dictionaries that you don't know the type of, simply change parameters of the Invoke method to any type:
setItemMethod.Invoke(dict, new object[] { 10, 50 }); // for integers

Demo

This is exactly what I needed and so simple.  Thank you!

((IDictionary)dict)[objKey] = objValue would be much more straightforward.

Entry is a struct.
So you are working with a copy of it, not the one that Dictionary internally uses.

Very good point and very good to know.  Thanks!
